# How to queryexactly when a field has long text in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have a filed with 100~300 characters. If I want to query this field, if I just use the sentences like:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "question": {
        "query":"asdasdasd",
        "minimum_should_match": "75%"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even if just tap the keyboard, I also can get some results.But these results are not relevant at all! I don't want to get them. What I can do to prevent the return of these results? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, did you tried with  a POST instead of a GET  ?

Comment: ummm...I do not know how to do search with POST. Could you give me a reference link?